# Bootstrap - Reducing the width of the Dashboard example

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page based on the bootstrap [Dashboard Example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/), and I want to reduce the width of the page, gaining something like ad space on the sides.

However, the side menu always stays nailed to the left side. Is there a way I can reduce the width of the overall page to 90%, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a width of 90% for the overall page, you need to adjust the navigation on the top, the menu on the side and the container with the main content:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top {
width: 90%;   
margin-left: auto;   
margin-right: auto;   
display: block;
}

.container-fluid {
width: 90%;   
margin-left: auto;   
margin-right: auto;   
display: block;
}

.sidebar {
left: 5%!important;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. BTW, can I also change the background color to the inverse kind? The white is kinda glaring.

Comment: Right now you are already using .navbar-inverse. But I think you mean you would want to have something like .navbar-default (see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default), right? Then you just need to change the the class name in the html but don't forget to adjust the css again ;)

Comment: Not quite. I wanted to give the background of the page, the area outside the navbar, sidebar and dashboard area the same color as the inverse color. The dashboard (placeholder) area would stay white, but if I use the inverse sidebar it stands out as a black square, so I would like the surrounding area to have the same color.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. Do you want to change the background color of the main content area or of the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

The side menu stays nailed to the left side because `left: 0` is applied to `.sidebar`.

You can add this to your css:

```
.sidebar {
  left: 5%!important;
}
```